# KSQL ignores Confluent Support Metric Collection config

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I've added the following line to my server.properties file:

```
confluent.support.metrics.enable=false
```

However, when KSQL starts up, it spits out the following:

```
Please note that the version check feature of KSQL is enabled.

...

By proceeding  with `confluent.support.metrics.enable=true`, you agree to
all such collection, transfer and use of Version information by Confluent. 
You can turn the version check  feature off by setting 
`confluent.support.metrics.enable=false` in the KSQL configuration and 
restarting the KSQL.  See the Confluent Platform documentation  for further information.
```

I know this properties file is being read and parsed by KSQL because it's pulling the other configs (like broker info) and reading that just fine. It's basically just ignoring my request to turn off metric collection. Any idea on how to actually turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug in KSQL. It was fixed here:
https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/2948